# problema ao enviar e-mail com css pelo phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Galera montei um e-mail usando html e css. O e-mail chega perfeito em vários e-mail, porem no G-mail o e-mail chega sem o css, ou seja apenas o html.

Alguém sabe como resolver o problema?

Segue o meu código do e-mail:

```
$email->Body = "
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        body {
            background-color: #F1F4F9;
        }
        table {
            width: 600px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-left:auto; 
            margin-right:auto;
        }
        .topo {
            text-align:center;
            background-color: #1E90FF;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .meio {
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            height: 300px;
            vertical-align: text-top;
        }
        .fim {
            text-align:center;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #1E90FF;
            height: 50px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .fim a{
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .titulo {
            text-align:center;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='topo'>
                MEU LOG AQUI
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='meio'>
                <p class='titulo'>TITULO</p>
                TEXTO DO E-MAIL  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='fim'>
                Estamos a disposição
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
";
```

Estou fazendo algo errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além da tag `CSS`, você terá que colocar os estilos também inline para que funcione no Gmail.

Algumas ferramentas podem auxiliar na conversão:

- http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/
- https://inliner.cm/

Veja também esse [guia](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) para saber o que pode e não pode usar em cada cliente de e-mail.

Comment: perfeito amigo, funcionou 100%. Me tira mais uma dúvida, estou tentando enviar um logo em svg, e não esta funcionando no g-mail. Qual a forma correta?

Comment: @HugoBorges eu nunca incluí SVG no template enviado. Faça o seguinte, abra uma nova pergunta com essa questão, eu realmente não sei responder porque nunca tentei.

Comment: a resolvi trocar por png. Vlw a ajuda por tudo :)